# Coordinate translation

Tags: geometry

I have one square where the max X/Y are 362 and the min X/Y are 0

I have another square with the following constraints:

xmin = -103680
xmax = 115968

ymin = -23808
ymax = 152544

Is there any way I can make it so coordinates given in the second square can be translated to be within the constraints of the first square?

Comment: Do you know the edges of the first square are parallel to the coordinate axes?  (This doesn't change the answer to your question, "yes", but it does change the proof a little.)

Comment: Also, by "max X/Y are 362", do you mean the maximum value of the ratio $X/Y$ is $362$ among all points $(X,Y)$ in the first square, or do you mean something else?

Comment: @EricTowers it is a 362x362 square

Comment: You still don't say whether its sides are parallel to the axes.  One can rotate a square.

Answer (score 1):

In the first square, the pixels are square because the range in $X$ and the range in $Y$ are the same.  In the second, the range of $X$ is $217648$ while the range in $Y$ is $176352$.  You can certainly do a linear transformation from the first range in each variable to the second.  If $X'$ is the new variable and $X$ is the old one, the transformation is $X'=X'_{min} + \frac {X'_{max}-X'_{min}}{X_{max}-X_{min}}(X-X_{min})$  This ignores any relation between $X$ and $Y$.  They are treated independently.